# How to return properties from specific HTML node from event path

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

I have a button with an image and text inside as follows:

```
<button on-tap="doSomething">
  <img src="./path/to/img.png">
  <p>Text<p>
</button>
```

And I'd like to pass the button text into a filter

```
function doSomething(e) {
  console.log(e.path[0].innerText);
}
```

However, the path changes depending on where the button is clicked. If the image is clicked instead of the button whitespace, the proper text as located at `e.path[0].innerText`.

I'm thinking I could loop through the path and return once the first button is found, but I'm not sure how to match the selector name.

```
function doSomething(e) {
  e.path.forEach(el => {
    if (el.name === 'button') console.log(el.innerText);
  }
}
```

Or I could bind data to both the image and button, but that seems like the wrong approach.

How can I select button from the path and retrieve its `innerText`?

Comment: `<button><p></p></button>` is invalid markup. [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) -> Permitted content -> _"[Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) but there must be no [Interactive content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#Interactive_content)"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `tagName` property with `target` element:

```js
function doSomething(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="doSomething(event)">
  <img src="./path/to/img.png">
  <p>Text<p>
</button>
```

---

Or:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    console.log(this.innerText);
  }
});
```

```html
<button>
  <img src="./path/to/img.png">
  <p>Text<p>
</button>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Tân!